# PHPUnit 10: parseTestMethodAnnotations() is not working as it is removed from PHPUnit/Util/Test

Tags: php, phpunit, phpunit-10

Recently I have upgraded from PHPUnit 9.6 to 10.4 and I am facing some difficulties while upgrading. For ex, I have below code:

```
use PHPUnit\Util\Test as TestUtil;

$annotations = TestUtil::parseTestMethodAnnotations(
    static::class,
    $this->name
);
```

To which I am getting error:

```
Caused By: Call to undefined method PHPUnit\Util\Test::parseTestMethodAnnotations()
```

Above error is coming as `parseTestMethodAnnotations()` is completely removed from PHPUnit 10 without any realtime alternative as fas as I know. I have gone through multiple PHPUnit 10 upgrade articles but still couldn't find anything that can replace the above functionality.

I need a realtime alternative to `TestUtil::parseTestMethodAnnotations()` in PHPUnit 10 or any other implementation which does the same work as this removed functionality.

I feel somehow it could be achieved with the help of `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Metadata/Parser/Annotation/DocBlock.php` but I couldn't find any example or usage of it so stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use the Registry as before. You can take a look at `RegistryTest` test for inspiration.

Comment: @soulseekah Thanks for the reply. I checked it, however I need the same array return which was coming from parseTestMethodAnnotations() in order to support the existing implementation. If I copy implementation of parseTestMethodAnnotations() in my method, then it is not an effective way I guess.